# Unable to call list from JSON file in dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

***functionality:***

I need to populate my dropdown menu with my json file.

***Issue:***

My dropdown list is unable to call the json objects in my json file, hence it is not populated. What have I done wrong in the json file call?

Please help.Thanks

***Code:***

```js
 $(function() {
   /*******************************************************
    *FUNCTION CALL TO POPULATE DROPDOWN MENU FROM JSON FILE*
    *******************************************************/
   $.getJSON("JSON/shops.json", function(obj) {
     $.each(obj.Shops, function(key, value) {
       $("#dropDownShops_1").append("<option>" + value.ShopsName + "</option>");
     });

     $.each(obj.Shops, function(key, value) {
       $("#dropDownShops_2").append("<option>" + value.ShopsName + "</option>");
     });
   });
 });
```

```css
#dropDownShops_1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
  height: 73px;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 250px;
  left: 450px;
}
#dropDownShops_2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
  height: 73px;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 650px;
  left: 450px;
}
```

```html
<select name="drop_down" id="dropDownShops_1">
  <option value="None" selected="Selected">Select Shops</option>
</select>

<select name="drop_down" id="dropDownShops_2">
  <option value="None" selected="Selected">Select Shops</option>
</select>
```

***JSON CODE FILE:***

```
{
"Shops": [
{
    "ShopName": "7en",
    "ShopID": "7en123",
    "Shoplocation": "#02-31"
}, {
    "ShopName": "8Taries",
    "ShopID": "8Taries123",
    "Shoplocation": "#B2-K4"
}, {
    "ShopName": "A|Xange",
    "ShopID": "A|Xange123",
    "Shoplocation": "#01-202"
}, {
    "ShopName": "Actiity",
    "ShopID": "Actiity123",
    "Shoplocation": "#02-38"
}, { 
    "ShopName": "Z Tnest", 
    "ShopID": "ZTnest123",
    "Shoplocation": "#B2-12"
}]   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its `ShopName`  not `ShopsName`

```js
var obj = {
  "Shops": [{
    "ShopName": "7en",
    "ShopID": "7en123",
    "Shoplocation": "#02-31"
  }, {
    "ShopName": "8Taries",
    "ShopID": "8Taries123",
    "Shoplocation": "#B2-K4"
  }, {
    "ShopName": "A|Xange",
    "ShopID": "A|Xange123",
    "Shoplocation": "#01-202"
  }, {
    "ShopName": "Actiity",
    "ShopID": "Actiity123",
    "Shoplocation": "#02-38"
  }, {
    "ShopName": "Z Tnest",
    "ShopID": "ZTnest123",
    "Shoplocation": "#B2-12"
  }]
}

$.each(obj.Shops, function(key, value) {
  $("#dropDownShops_1,#dropDownShops_2").append("<option>" + value.ShopName + "</option>");
});
```

```css
#dropDownShops_1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
  height: 73px;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 250px;
  left: 450px;
}
#dropDownShops_2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
  height: 73px;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 650px;
  left: 450px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="drop_down" id="dropDownShops_1">
  <option value="None" selected="Selected">Select Shops</option>
</select>

<select name="drop_down" id="dropDownShops_2">
  <option value="None" selected="Selected">Select Shops</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I have 300 hundred over items in the var, hence I need to have a separate jSON file. I have just changed it to shopName, but it is still not populating the dropdown menu from the jSon file

Comment: are you sure this is the exact file structure of the json?

Comment: how do you trigger this ajax call?

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by the exact file structure of the json?

Comment: I am triggering my json file via `$.getJSON("JSON/shops.json", function(obj) {....}`

Comment: the following is within the JSON file folder while the JSON file folder is in the same root folder as the current working fie

Comment: do a console.log(obj) and paste the result here, thank you

Comment: I don't think it is calling the following $.getJSON() method, as I have input console.log in the following `$.getJSON("JSON/shops.json", function(obj) {console.log("obj:" +obj);....});` and nothing is shown in my console.log

Comment: what event triggers it?

Comment: It is called within : `$(function() {... });` so it is called on document.getready

Comment: do you have any console errors, if you don't have that means you json file is empty

Comment: there is no console errors. but I have populated the json file though

Comment: @Luke on a side note, when youre doing a `console.log()` you should use a comma instead of a plus sign. That way youll be able to see the structure of the object in the console. `console.log("obj:", obj);` instead of `console.log("obj:" +obj);`

Comment: how does the body of the xhr request look like?

Comment: I did not do any xhr request though. I am requesting it direct from the json file path

Comment: are you sure, xhr means ajax request

Comment: yes, i didn't use ajax request to call jsonfile. The only way I did is $.getJSON().. That was the only method i am currently using to call the JSON file

Comment: getJSON() is ajax  man did you even read the documentation for jquery?

Comment: I did. but from the documentation you have to declare a var to the get.JSON() in which i didn't do

Comment: Then the body as requested by you would be `/*******************************************************
            *FUNCTION CALL TO POPULATE DROPDOWN MENU FROM JSON FILE*
            *******************************************************/
            $.getJSON("JSON/shops.json", function(obj) {

                console.log("obj:" +obj);
                $.each(obj.Shops, function(key, value) {
                    $("#dropDownShops_1,#dropDownShops_2").append("<option>" + value.ShopName + "</option>");
                });
            });`,don't understand what you are trying to find out